# How to return specific values in an array?

Tags: java, arrays

Simply, I have a set of numbers like this.

```
int targetNumber = 8;

int[] n = new int[4];
n[0] = 2;
n[1] = 4;
n[2] = 8;
n[3] = 16;
```

Now, I'm trying to return 3 numbers.

For example, since `n[2]` is equal to the `targetNumber`, I want to return `n[0]`, `n[1]`, and `n[3]`.

Any ways on how I can do that?

Comment: You can only return one object or primitive. You could, for example, return a smaller array with the values you want, or define an object with related fields then set those fields and return the object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make use of the interface [Stream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html)

```
Arrays.stream(n)
.filter(value -> value != targetNumber)
.limit(3)/*if you want to print only the first three results*/
.forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: Thanks, I recently started learning about Java streams, and this answer is very helpful for me.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it in classic fashion:

```
for (int i : n) {
    if (i != targetNumber)
        System.out.println(i);
}
```

output will be `n[0]`, `n[1]` and `n[3]`

```
2
4
16
```

Comment: I thought the question was getting only three numbers :)

Comment: @Dev.Joel your answer is valid I think it might be over complicated for OP, I like streams but maybe OP have not enough knowledge of streams yet. any way I give my vote for you as well. I think also he mean 3 remain numbers of 4

Comment: It is also possible that the focus of the question is to return 3 items because the array is 4. I understood back 3 items generally equal his response was accepted because it was what he wanted the OP. all right

Comment: I agree but I think still the only reason OP did not get it because it is new stuff to him/her to understand any nice chatting with you.